# SharePoint 2010 SSAS SSRS transition 2 servers from one FARM to another 1 server FARM

Tags: sql-server, powershell, sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010

We have an Enterprise server BI Farm consisting of three(3) Servers. FARM2 on SQL2 instance

1) Central Admin Server
 2) PowerPivot SSAS Server
 3) SSRS Reporting Server.

We would like to combine all of these servers (omitting the CA) into a One server Farm FARM1  currently FARM1 does not have SSAS or SSRS BI services installed. Thus there is another external database already in place for FARM1 - SQL1.

These three servers FARM2 and the SQL2 instance will be decommisioned but we do not want to lose the reports, subscriptions and artifacts in FARM2 or currently in SQL2 during transition.

What would be the easiest way to do this with the least amount of risk? 
All are SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and SQL2012 on OS SERVER2010

Are there powershell scripts availble to accomplish this? If so what are they?

What is the procedure for this merge? Please include backup and recovery.

Thanks in advance!